# Ayuda para hacer un cronometro en arduino con un RTC

Tags: arduino

soy nuevo en el mundo de arduino y he estado tratando de hacer un cronometro utilizando los valores que me entrega la librería RTClib.h de un RTC, ya hice un contador por software con millis() pero quiero usar el RTC como referencia el problema es que no encuentro una manera de usar los valores del RTC.

Mi proyecto consiste en usar dos entradas del arduino para leer cuando un boton este cerrado inicie el conteo, cuando este abierto detenga el conteo y guarde esos datos hasta que el otro boton sea accionado y lo resetee. Aún no sé cómo podría hacerlo.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda y sus ideas, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no entiendo exactamente lo que necesitas, según lo que entiendo, pon en tu loop una condición de estado con el botón, cuando se apriete por primera vez llama una función que te retorne el valor dado por el RTC, mientras no se presione de nuevo sigue tomando el valor en un contador.

Ejemplo del botón, counterT contiene un valor booleano que le permite conocer su estatus

```
void loop() {
  if (counterT != ISRcounterT) {
    resultSerialT = "El botón se presionó, estado";
    resultSerialT += (counterT % 2 == 0) ? " bajo." : " alto.";
    Serial.println(resultSerialT);
    counterT = ISRcounterT;
  }
}
```

Ejemplo del RTC, la función retorna la hora

```
void getDateT(DateTime date) {
  timeT = String(date.hour(), DEC) + ":" + String(date.minute(), DEC) + ":" + String(date.second(), DEC);
}
```

Solo aplica la lógica necesaria y funcionara. Los códigos los obtuve de una muy buena página llamada [TEOS](https://proyecto-teos.com/). Checa sus repos en [github](https://github.com/proyectoTEOS) del botón y RTC y podrás obtener más información.